# Thymeleaf form input text for save Set<Object>

Tags: spring, hibernate, thymeleaf

I have an Entity with `@OneToMany` association:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "house", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Room> rooms;
```

Then in Thymeleaf I would like to populate four input text fields in order to save four rooms into DB.

The question is how to populate these fields to proper database save via Hibernate?

```
<tr th:each="i,iterStat : ${#numbers.sequence( 1, 4)}">    
  <td>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{????}" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to create another entity ie Room of type room
with the property ie description

then in the house entity

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "house", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Room> rooms
```

In your controller before you go to the page you can initialise house and then initialise 4 rooms and set rooms to the house.

So

```
Set<Room> h = new HashSet<Room>();
for (i=0;i<4;i++){
  Room room = new Room();
  h.add(room);
}
House house = new House();
shouse.setRooms(h);
```

Then in your html form you can have the house object

```
<form id=".." th:action=".." th:object="${house}" method="post">
```

and then you can have

```
<tr th:each="i,iterStat : ${house.rooms}">    
  <td>
    <input type="text" th:field="${i.description}" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

Hope this helps